# Jquery-ui not working after loading content with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using `jquery-ui` to sort the items on my list. At first load I have no problem coz it works fine but after I go to other page and go back to the page where my list is. That's the time I'm having trouble.

By the way, I'm using AJAX to load the content of my pages. And it seems that `jquery-ui` can't read the content that was loaded by AJAX. I need to refresh the page again so that it will work fine.

I created sample [**`here:`**](https://jsfiddle.net/junscrapers/3x4cpau4/)

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="btnWrapper">
    <button onclick="showPage1();">Page 1</button>
    <button onclick="showPage2();">Page 2</button>
</div>

 <div id="desp">
 <ul id="sortable">
  <li><span></span>Item 1</li>
  <li><span></span>Item 2</li>
  <li><span></span>Item 3</li>
  <li><span></span>Item 4</li>
</ul>
 </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

My JS Code:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );

  function showPage1(){
    $('#desp').html(
        '<ul id="sortable">'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>'+
        '</ul>'
      );
  }

    function showPage2(){
    $('#desp').html('<h3>Page 2 here...<h3>');
  }
```

In my example, at first load, no problem. But as you click page2 and go back to Page1, sort function will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `ISSUE`

You are overriding the html and creating a new element with `#sortable`, you need to call sortable too `$( "#sortable" ).sortable();` inside your `showPage1()`

```
function showPage1(){
    $('#desp').html(
        '<ul id="sortable">'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>'+
          '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>'+
        '</ul>'
      );
      $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  }
```

### `BEST APPROACH`

A better approach will be to detect changes inside the `#desp` div and call `sortable()` so you dont have to call it manually every time in every other ajax call where you are populating the sortable html again.

```
$('#desp').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

See [**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/3x4cpau4/33/) here

or a Demo Below with full code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

$('#desp').on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});

function showPage1() {
  $('#desp').html(
    '<ul id="sortable">' +
    '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>' +
    '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>' +
    '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>' +
    '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>' +
    '</ul>'
  );
  /*     $( "#sortable" ).sortable(); */
}

function showPage2() {
  $('#desp').html('<h3>Page 2 here...<h3>');
}
```

```css
#btnWrapper {
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
}

#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#sortable li {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

#sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnWrapper">
  <button onclick="showPage1();">Page 1</button>
  <button onclick="showPage2();">Page 2</button>
</div>

<div id="desp">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li><span></span>Item 1</li>
    <li><span></span>Item 2</li>
    <li><span></span>Item 3</li>
    <li><span></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solves the problem. I tried to put the $( "#sortable" ).sortable(); code inside the showPage1() function but it was before the $('#desp').html() line.  That's why it didn't work. :) Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the code please recheck and use the `$('#desp').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){` so that you dont have to call it every time @Jun

Comment: Okey, I appreciate that @Muhammad. That surely helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `sortable()` here

```
function showPage1(){
$('#desp').html(
    '<ul id="sortable">'+
      '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>'+
      '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>'+
      '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>'+
      '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>'+
    '</ul>'
  );
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();

}
```